# Kafka server hanging with Java 17 and security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL

Tags: apache-kafka, java-17

Kafka server is hanging with Java 17 and security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL property. Below is the line it shows and hangs

```
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,883] INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9093. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
```

Running with latest kafka `3.3.2` binary and Java `17.0.6`. It works fine when I change to Java `11`.

**Broker Config:**

```
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, SSL://localhost:9093
ssl.keystore.type=PKCS12
ssl.keystore.location=/config/kafka-local-test.local.pfx
ssl.keystore.password=hello
ssl.key.password=hello
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

**Logs:**

```
hello@world bin % ./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
[2023-02-07 21:35:46,981] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,130] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,179] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,180] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,180] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,187] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to localhost:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.3--6401e4ad2087061bc6b9f80dec2d69f2e3c8660a, built on 04/08/2021 16:35 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:host.name=hello.com (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:java.version=17.0.6 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Homebrew (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:java.home=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.6/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/connect-api-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/connect-json-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.13.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.34.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.34.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.34.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.34.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.34.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.34.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jline-3.21.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/jose4j-0.7.9.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-metadata-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-raft-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-server-common-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-shell-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-storage-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-storage-api-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.13-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/kafka_2.13-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.8.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/metrics-core-4.1.12.1.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.78.Final.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/reload4j-1.2.19.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-7.1.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.6.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.13-1.0.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.13.8.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.13.8.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/swagger-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/trogdor-3.3.2.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/hello/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/3k/xxhlnq1j0y3_d6pvvtyy3_m80000gp/T/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,193] INFO Client environment:os.name=Mac OS X (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:os.arch=aarch64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:os.version=13.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:user.name=hello (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:user.home=/Users/hello (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/Users/hello/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.3.2/bin (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=987MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,194] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,195] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@6b0d80ed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,200] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,202] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,203] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,210] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,211] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,223] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,223] INFO SASL config status: Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,228] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:49225, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,313] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, session id = 0x3000405075a003f, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,315] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,472] INFO Cluster ID = YZq8o9BBQ4y0HWo2u1vpGQ (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,502] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
    advertised.listeners = null
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    authorizer.class.name = 
    auto.create.topics.enable = true
    auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
    background.threads = 10
    broker.heartbeat.interval.ms = 2000
    broker.id = -1
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    broker.rack = null
    broker.session.timeout.ms = 9000
    client.quota.callback.class = null
    compression.type = producer
    connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
    control.plane.listener.name = null
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.listener.names = null
    controller.quorum.append.linger.ms = 25
    controller.quorum.election.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    controller.quorum.election.timeout.ms = 1000
    controller.quorum.fetch.timeout.ms = 2000
    controller.quorum.request.timeout.ms = 2000
    controller.quorum.retry.backoff.ms = 20
    controller.quorum.voters = []
    controller.quota.window.num = 11
    controller.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 1
    delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
    delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
    delegation.token.master.key = null
    delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
    delegation.token.secret.key = null
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    early.start.listeners = null
    fetch.max.bytes = 57671680
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
    group.max.size = 2147483647
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    initial.broker.registration.timeout.ms = 60000
    inter.broker.listener.name = null
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 3.3-IV3
    kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
    kafka.metrics.reporters = []
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    listeners = PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, SSL://localhost:9093
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 3.0-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 168
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = null
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connection.creation.rate = 2147483647
    max.connections = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
    max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
    message.max.bytes = 1048588
    metadata.log.dir = null
    metadata.log.max.record.bytes.between.snapshots = 20971520
    metadata.log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    metadata.log.segment.min.bytes = 8388608
    metadata.log.segment.ms = 604800000
    metadata.max.idle.interval.ms = 500
    metadata.max.retention.bytes = -1
    metadata.max.retention.ms = 604800000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    node.id = -1
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    password.encoder.iterations = 4096
    password.encoder.key.length = 128
    password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
    password.encoder.old.secret = null
    password.encoder.secret = null
    principal.builder.class = class org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.DefaultKafkaPrincipalBuilder
    process.roles = []
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    remote.log.index.file.cache.total.size.bytes = 1073741824
    remote.log.manager.task.interval.ms = 30000
    remote.log.manager.task.retry.backoff.max.ms = 30000
    remote.log.manager.task.retry.backoff.ms = 500
    remote.log.manager.task.retry.jitter = 0.2
    remote.log.manager.thread.pool.size = 10
    remote.log.metadata.manager.class.name = null
    remote.log.metadata.manager.class.path = null
    remote.log.metadata.manager.impl.prefix = null
    remote.log.metadata.manager.listener.name = null
    remote.log.reader.max.pending.tasks = 100
    remote.log.reader.threads = 10
    remote.log.storage.manager.class.name = null
    remote.log.storage.manager.class.path = null
    remote.log.storage.manager.impl.prefix = null
    remote.log.storage.system.enable = false
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 30000
    replica.selector.class = null
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.server.max.receive.size = 524288
    security.inter.broker.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    socket.listen.backlog.size = 50
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = []
    ssl.client.auth = required
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = /config/kafka-local-test.local.pfx
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = PKCS12
    ssl.principal.mapping.rules = DEFAULT
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 10000
    transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
    transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
    zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket = null
    zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 18000
    zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 18000
    zookeeper.set.acl = false
    zookeeper.ssl.cipher.suites = null
    zookeeper.ssl.client.enable = false
    zookeeper.ssl.crl.enable = false
    zookeeper.ssl.enabled.protocols = null
    zookeeper.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = HTTPS
    zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location = null
    zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password = null
    zookeeper.ssl.keystore.type = null
    zookeeper.ssl.ocsp.enable = false
    zookeeper.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location = null
    zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password = null
    zookeeper.ssl.truststore.type = null
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,520] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,520] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,521] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,522] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-ControllerMutation]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,554] INFO Loading logs from log dirs ArraySeq(/tmp/kafka-logs) (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,555] INFO Skipping recovery for all logs in /tmp/kafka-logs since clean shutdown file was found (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,564] INFO Loaded 0 logs in 10ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,564] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,565] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,625] INFO [feature-zk-node-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener$ChangeNotificationProcessorThread)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,635] INFO [MetadataCache brokerId=0] Updated cache from existing <empty> to latest FinalizedFeaturesAndEpoch(features=Map(), epoch=1). (kafka.server.metadata.ZkMetadataCache)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,737] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=forwarding]: Starting (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,869] INFO Updated connection-accept-rate max connection creation rate to 2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,872] INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9092. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,883] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2023-02-07 21:35:47,883] INFO Updated connection-accept-rate max connection creation rate to 2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
########### HANGS HERE [2023-02-07 21:35:47,883] INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9093. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)                          
^C[2023-02-07 21:36:34,604] INFO Terminating process due to signal SIGINT (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2023-02-07 21:36:34,605] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-02-07 21:36:34,607] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer shutdown. (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kafka server is still starting up, cannot shut down!
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:708)
    at kafka.Kafka$.$anonfun$main$3(Kafka.scala:100)
    at kafka.utils.Exit$.$anonfun$addShutdownHook$1(Exit.scala:38)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2023-02-07 21:36:34,609] ERROR Halting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)
```

Does anyone know what I need to set to make it work?

Comment: You're likely going to need to add more details to your question for the community to help you.  Consider adding the full broker config, detailing the number of brokers etc, and the complete logs.

Also, is this Java version specific? i.e. does it start ok if you use a different JDK version?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Added more details.

Comment: Are you sure Kafka supports Java 17 yet? Also, `Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9093` means it is **running and accepting connections**. Why do you expect it to not "hang"? Have you tried running producers/consumers in other terminals while it "hangs"?

Comment: Yes as per them it is available from `3.1.0`. You should see a log like below if it is successfully start accepting connection on port `9093`.


[SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)